# launching SMS app when app starts

Tags: ios, sms

I need to open the pre installed SMS app in iPhone.
I know how to open SMS app using `MFMessageUI` class, but the problem is that it can be used to display it as a modal view which in turns requires a view controller.

Does anybody know how to populate it in AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:1234567890"]];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *stringURL = @"sms:+12345678901";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

This :)

Comment: This is just a copy of beryllium's answer with slight style differences.

Comment: @JamesWebster sorry, i don't see the other answer, my fault :)